# covariance of autocorrelated time series

Tags: econometrics, time-series

When we calculate the variance of a time series with autocorrelation, we need to do some shrinkage to get the correct value. What about say we have two time series, X, Y. both have autocorrelations. Will that effect the correlation Cor(X, Y)? What about the Cov(X, Y)? What kind of adjustment is needed?

Comment: Please be (much) more explicit about what do you mean by "we need to do some shrinkage".

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos for example, you could regress the time series on a constant, then use Newey West to adjust for residual covariance matrix. You will get an beta with adjust variance, and this variance is your time series variance.